# Can't access static resources (.html) files in Apache Tomcat 7.0.52

Tags: html, apache, file, tomcat7

Even though I found some similar queries on the topic but can't find any answer suitable to my problem. My requirement is as follows -

I have installed my app (MyApp) in webapps dir of Apache Tomcat ver 7 web server. The dir structure is

```
/
 |
 |----api/
 |
 |----WEB-INF/
 |
 |----META-INF/
```

I have some static html files in the "api" dir(say index.html) which I want to access in the following way through a browser - `http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/index.html`

However, I can't access any static resources (html files) in this way. As far as I know any static outside WEB-INF can be accessed directly through the browser but I can't do it.

### My web.xml looks something like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
          <param-value>com.mycomp.MyApp</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myapp/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping> 
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
```

I'll appreciate any good help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the value for the tag url-pattern with some different name like /rest/* instead of myapp.
Now try accessing your url.